# annotate sum of annotated values in related model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-annotate

I have these models:

```
class Product(..):
    category = ForeignKey('InputCategory...

class InputCategory(MPTTModel):
   route_to = ForeignKey('RoutingCategory...

class RoutingCategory(MPTTModel):
   pass
```

So `InputCategory` has many `Products` and `RoutingCategory` has many `InputCategory` objects.

I can annotate `product_count` for an `InputCategory`:

```
InputCategory.objects.annotate(product_count=Count('products'))
```

But I need to have `product_count` annotated to the `RoutingCategory`.

How can I do that?

I tried to modify `Manager` for `InputCategory` and do this:

```
RoutingCategory.objects.annotate(product_count=Sum('input_categories__product_count'))
```

But it says: `FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'product_count' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.`

Obviously I should have override related Manager.

Do you know how to do that?

**EDIT**

@Willem Van Onsem came up with this answer which works:

```
from django.db.models import Count
RoutingCategory.objects.annotate(
    product_count=Count('input_categories__products')
)
```

But I have annotated also `product_cumulative_count` which counts products of self and all ancestors of the `InputCategory`. I would like to access this sum of this counts too from the `RoutingCategory`.

I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a problem with this is that Django does *not* use the `.objects` manager to access the related model. But even if it did, it would not work (well). SQL does not allow such multilevel GROUP BYs, or at least not without first making a query, and then using that result in another query.

You however do not need that anyway, you can just `Count` the related products here:

```
from django.db.models import Count

RoutingCategory.objects.annotate(
    product_count=Count('input_categories__products')
)
```

Comment: Maybe I have another (similar) problem. I've added an edit to the bottom of the question. Feel free to check it, thanks.